# Spotify API get request with kotlin retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, spotify

I am trying to get [new-releases](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/#/operations/get-new-releases) from Spotify API, but it returns only object with null fields

Here's my retrfofit interface :

```
interface SpotifyApiService {

@GET("browse/new-releases")
suspend fun getAlbums(
    @Query("limit") limit: Int,
    @Header("Authorization") authorization: String
): Albums

// gets authorization token
@POST("api/token")
@FormUrlEncoded
suspend fun getToken(
    @Header("Authorization") auth: String,
    @Header("Content-Type") content: String,
    @Field("grant_type") grantType: String
): TokenResponse
```

}

Albums data class:

```
@kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
data class Albums(
    val limit: Int,
    val next: String,
    val previous: String,
    val total: Int,
    val items: List<Album> 
)
```

Response object i get:
[image]

What can I do? I've tried add all required parameters as spotify api reference says but it didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: i declared new class with albums field of type Albums and make it as returned type of request function type